# Sort files according to kind in Office for Mac save dialog

Tags: finder, ms-office

I would like to arrange my folders above files so that finding where I want to file project details becomes more straightforward.

I have been able to do this in Finder but when using Office for Mac applications like Word or Excel and trying to "save" a file, all the existing files and folders are mixed up according to name – not kind.

Can anyone help me "sort" this out?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is covered in this [microsoft forum discussion](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/can-i-get-the-open-dialog-to-sort-files-by-label/0071f54f-c243-4972-a837-0e6f9e8a428a?msgId=75ee8b98-a694-4d5b-9497-ec5efdaff9ee), but in essence what you need to do is

- switch to list view in the file dialog
- be sure "Kind" is one of the columns shown

  - if it isn't, hold "control" and click on the bar with column names
  - select "Kind" to show that row
- then you can click on the "Kind" header to sort, and all folders will be together.

This doesn't put folders at the top though. If you really want to do that, you can read the solution someone devised there. The labelled every folder, then sort in list view not by kind, but by label.